# R : select only the maximum value from each columns based on row in R

Tags: r, max, stat

I just want to select the max value from each column, so the dimension of the result will be same as the amount of column.

[image: predicted prob]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `apply(MY_DATA, 2, max)`

for example with `mtcars` a default dataset build into R

```
> apply(mtcars,2, max)
    mpg     cyl    disp      hp    drat      wt    qsec      vs      am    gear    carb 
 33.900   8.000 472.000 335.000   4.930   5.424  22.900   1.000   1.000   5.000   8.000
```

The `apply` function applies a function row-by-row (`1`) or column-by-column (`2`). Here I'm applying a function that returns the maximum on a column-by-column basis.